# variable value is changing without scanf call

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working with openGL in C++ and while I was taking input for the vertices in a loop, I encountered a problem where the number of vertices is changing with the input of the input value, although I am not swapping the variable.

Here the variable that I am in trouble with is numPoints, I have declared it at the top with the include lines (to try to make it global, I am originally from Java). and the value changes when the input loop value changes to i == 2. I am taking two values from keyboard, x and y. The detailed code with the main function is given below.

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif


#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdio.h"

int pointValx[0];
int pointValy[0];
int numPoint;

void takeInput()
{
printf("Screen Size is 0 - 400 in X and 0 - 500 in Y\n");
printf("Lab for Line and Point\n");
printf("number of lines >> \n");
scanf("%d",&numPoint); //comment this line for Line

pointValx[numPoint];
pointValy[numPoint];

printf("numPoint >> %d\n",numPoint);

for(int i = 0; i < numPoint;)
{
    int x,y;
    printf("Input for X >> %d\n", i);
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("numPoint >> %d\n",numPoint);
    if(x >= 0 && x <= 400)
    {
        printf("Input for Y >> %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d",&y);
        if(y >= 0 && y <= 500)
        {
            pointValx[i] = x;
            pointValy[i] = y;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Y value crossed the limit\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
       printf("X value crossed the limit\n");
    }
   }

   printf("End of Input file\n");
 }


/// MAIN FUNCTION

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int win;

glutInit(&argc, argv);      /* initialize GLUT system */

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(400,500);        /* width=400pixels height=500pixels */
win = glutCreateWindow("GL_LINES and Points");  /* create window */

/* from this point on the current window is win */
takeInput();

glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);  /* set background to black */
gluOrtho2D(0,400,0,500);        /* how object is mapped to window */
glutDisplayFunc(displayCB);     /* set window's display callback */

glutMainLoop();         /* start processing events... */

/* execution never reaches this point */

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pointValx[numPoint];
pointValy[numPoint];
```

This code doesn't do what you think it does

It accesses the value at index `numPoint` and then does nothing with it. Accessing the value itself is undefined behavior.

What you should do is declare them as pointer and then allocate the arrays.

```
int* pointValx;
int* pointValy;

void takeInput()
{
printf("Screen Size is 0 - 400 in X and 0 - 500 in Y\n");
printf("Lab for Line and Point\n");
printf("number of lines >> \n");
scanf("%d",&numPoint); //comment this line for Line

pointValx = (int*)malloc(numPoint*sizeof(int));
pointValy = (int*)malloc(numPoint*sizeof(int));
```

and after you are done with them you should free them:

```
free(pointValx);
free(pointValy);
```

Comment: I have done this but I am getting an error > invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] in the line where I have allocated the memory to those pointer, pointValx and pointValy

Comment: @MDKamalHossainShajal Then you need to cast it using `pointValx = (int*)malloc(numPoint*sizeof(int));`

Comment: @MDKamalHossainShajal That indicates that you really are programming in C++, even though you don't use any C++ functionality or functions. Then I really implore you to learn C++ properly, including using `std::vector` instead of pointers. Check [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for beginners books and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is these two arrays:

```
int pointValx[0];
int pointValy[0];
```

Here you declare two arrays of size zero. Any indexing in them will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Arrays are fixed when you compile your program, you can't change the size later at runtime. If you want to change the size at runtime, then you need to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead (which is what I recommend) or allocate them dynamically using pointers and `new[]`.

Comment: but I redefined their size in the takeInput() method. plus, I have checked to take input till i = 10 before I force quit it.

Comment: @MDKamalHossainShajal But you ***can't*** change the size of an array at runtime, it is fixed when you compile your program.

Comment: Oh. okay but I need to access these arrays from anywhere I want in this file. How can I do so then?

Comment: He is using C (at least according to his tags) so `new[]` and `vector` aren't available

Comment: @ratchetfreak I was looking at the original tag, before the edit.

Comment: @MDKamalHossainShajal If you are using C (not C++ as you originally tagged your question) then use `malloc` to dynamically allocate the "arrays". And you have two ways of getting access to these arraya from all parts of the program: Pass the ***pointers*** as arguments to the functions that needs them (my recommendation) or keep the pointer variables as global variables, just like now.